# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer inconsistency issue

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` (as part of a custom pop gesture) that works 85-90% of the time. There's that 10-15% when it just doesn't fire no matter how perfectly you swipe. The `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` is competing with a `UIScrollView` that contains the navigation controller which also detects gestures in the same direction (horizontal) so I suspect that may be the issue.

Is this relatively common to have a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` fire inconsistently, particularly when `UIKit` has to take its best guess if the gesture is a screen-edge pop or a regular pan? And is there a way to reconfigure `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to get it working with a higher success rate, perhaps by enlarging the rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent UIScrollView's UIPanGestureRecognizer from blocking UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer:

```
[scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer];
```

This method creates a relationship with another gesture recognizer that delays the receiver’s transition out of UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible.